# Strange issue with a border going to the above div?

Tags: html, css, border

I want my bordered div to look like:

[image: this]

neat and just wrapped around the div right under the two img divs. (Adding a hyphen or period separates the div to separate and lets it go below).

but instead, I'm getting

[image: this]

where it looks like it's going up and hooking to the above divs — ideas?

This is my css:

```
tallcrop {
    width: 49%;
    height: 55vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    align: left;
    display: inline-block;}

tallcrop img{
    position:center;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;}

.leftside {
  margin-top: .5%;
  padding-right: 1%; 
  padding-bottom: 1.5%;
  padding-top: 0%;}

.rightside {
  margin-top: .5%;
  padding-left: 1%; 
  padding-bottom: 1.5%;
  padding-top: 0%;}

fluid box {
  width: 100%;}

fluidbox p {
  border: .06em solid black;
  height: ;
  font-face:'ag';
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 1%;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<!--Fires--> 
<tallcrop class="leftside">
  <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/598ca765c534a5280a3fb1ef/t/59c043674c0dbf745deee657/1505772425232/DSC_0909.jpg"></tallcrop>

<!--Small Editions--> 
<tallcrop class="rightside"><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/598ca765c534a5280a3fb1ef/t/59c04447be42d644772fc2bf/1505772633670/Small_Editions1.jpg"></tallcrop>

<!--Fluid--> 
<fluidbox>
  <p>On the Democratic <font face="ab">Fluidity</font> of Digital Artist Books</p></fluidbox>
```

Comment: Don't make up HTML elements...unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: We're all just trying our best, relax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **float** for the left and right alignment. If you are using this property you must need to use `clear: both` CSS property.
Elements after a floating element will flow around it. To avoid this, use the clear property or the clearfix hack as given below.
I have added this **HTML** tag below the **tallcrop** tag:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

Here is the demo:

```css
tallcrop {
    width: 49%;
    height: 55vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    align: left;
    display: inline-block;}

tallcrop img{
    position:center;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;}

.leftside {
  margin-top: .5%;
  padding-right: 1%; 
  padding-bottom: 1.5%;
  padding-top: 0%;}

.rightside {
  margin-top: .5%;
  padding-left: 1%; 
  padding-bottom: 1.5%;
  padding-top: 0%;}

fluid box {
  width: 100%;}

fluidbox p {
  border: .06em solid black;
  
  font-face:'ag';
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 1%;
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!--Fires--> 

<tallcrop class="leftside">
  <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/598ca765c534a5280a3fb1ef/t/59c043674c0dbf745deee657/1505772425232/DSC_0909.jpg"></tallcrop>

<!--Small Editions--> 
<tallcrop class="rightside"><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/598ca765c534a5280a3fb1ef/t/59c04447be42d644772fc2bf/1505772633670/Small_Editions1.jpg"></tallcrop>

<!--Fluid--> 

<div class="clearfix"></div> 
<fluidbox>
  <p>On the Democratic <font face="ab">Fluidity</font> of Digital Artist Books</p></fluidbox>
```

You can also edit it on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/satheesh_design/pen/oGxNea).

Comment: If you feel that answers given is good enough, please give a credits to those who spending time for you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It is because you haven't cleared your floats and also as you are using custom html elements, it doesn't know what type of element it is (ie inline, block, etc). You can fix your code with the following:

```
fluidbox {  /* remove the space between fluid and box in your css */
  width: 100%;
  display:block;  /* make it a block element */
  clear:left;     /* clear your left float */
}
```

Your fixed code:

```css
tallcrop {
  width: 49%;
  height: 55vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

tallcrop img {
  position: center;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.leftside {
  margin-top: .5%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1.5%;
  padding-top: 0%;
}

.rightside {
  margin-top: .5%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1.5%;
  padding-top: 0%;
}

fluidbox {
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
  clear:left;
}

fluidbox p {
  border: .06em solid black;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 1%;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!--Fires-->

<tallcrop class="leftside">
  <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/598ca765c534a5280a3fb1ef/t/59c043674c0dbf745deee657/1505772425232/DSC_0909.jpg"></tallcrop>

<!--Small Editions-->
<tallcrop class="rightside"><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/598ca765c534a5280a3fb1ef/t/59c04447be42d644772fc2bf/1505772633670/Small_Editions1.jpg"></tallcrop>

<!--Fluid-->

<fluidbox>
  <p>On the Democratic
    <font face="ab">Fluidity</font> of Digital Artist Books</p>
</fluidbox>
```